# Free touch-typing tutor for Mac?

Tags: gratis, osx, productivity

I am looking for an application to help me learn to touch-type quickly, since all my friends are able to do so and I am lagging behind.

My minimum requirements are (in order):

- that it is mac-compatible (i have a mid-2011 iMac with OS X El Cap)
- that it is free to download and use
- it would be nice if there is one available on the Mac App store but a regular .zip or .dmg download will work as well

I already have the free Mac App "Typist" but that app doesn't make me feel very motivated to come back and keep trying. I need something that looks a little more professional.

Thanks in advance,

DeveloperACE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned to type with all 10 fingers on https://www.typing.com/ and also used https://www.typingclub.com/. No need to download any software, works directly from any modern browser.

They are great because they provide all the instructions you need to position your hands correctly on the keyboard, practice all combinations of letters that are rather complicated to type. They also support different keyboard layout like QWERTY / AZERTY.

Comment: Typing in parallel? What's that?

Comment: typo, sorry, fixed